# Can I use CSS keyframes to animate SVGs used as background images for elements?

Tags: css, svg, css-animations

In my HTML page I have a div that has an external svg as a background 
`background-image: url('mybg.svg');`

Inside that svg I have a polyline to which I have assigned a class name:
`<polyline class="bg1svg" stroke="#000000" points=".."`

How canI trigger changes or animations of that element with `@keyframes` in the main page? When I invoke JQuery to get the element by class, like `$('.bg1svg')` it returns a blank array and I think it may not be able to target elements in a separate file, even if it gets used as a background image.

Comment: You can't affect an extenal SVG file with CSS...and certainly not one that's a bg image. You'd have to build the animation into the SVG code.

Comment: thanks for the answer. it currently is like that but I get warning messages in the browser that SMIL animations will get deprecated soon.

Comment: You can embed a `style` tag in the SVG though - http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/styling.html#StyleElement